# Jquery Datatable Editor Where Clause with Special Characters

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

Good afternoon,

I'm using Jquery Datatable Editor to manage a table and whenever I have a company name with a special character in it, the query fails.

I already have it set as UTF8 and it's still not working. Any ideas?

```
   $db->sql( 'set names utf8' );

  ->where('nextgenorder_companyname', 'StackOverflow/ Test: Name', '=')
```

If the company name doesn't have special characters, it works perfectly fine:

```
   $db->sql( 'set names utf8' );

  ->where('nextgenorder_companyname', 'StackOverflow', '=')
```

I tried adding the following header to each page and its still not working:

```
  header( 'content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

***UPDATE***

After more troubleshooting, this is what i found:

The company name in the table has an extra space. This is how the company name is listed in the table:

```
 125 Broadway LLC 
 c/o Properties, Inc
```

And on my backend page, i'm matching it like this:

```
 ->where('nextgenorder_companyname', $_GET['editor_nextgenorder_companyname'], '=')
```

I'm still having issues. Please help.

Comment: I think you have to make sure your request is correct in first place. try debugging which search phrase arrives at your ajax endpoint.

Comment: It is correct. Again, if the company name does not have a special character it works perfectly fine. It does not work when the name has special characters.

Comment: you could use `like` and you could normalize both versions (db value and search term) with eg. `lolower` or `replace`